# Convert re.match/re.search to string

Tags: python, regex

I've been looking through having `re.match`/`re.search` find a certain int from my file. The int will differ, which is why I'm using regex in the first place. Here is the file:

```
Money:
*1,000 coins
*2 dollars
```

And my code:

```
import re
amount = 2
price = 500 * amount
with open("money.txt", "r") as money:
    moneyc = money.read()
    moneyc = moneyc.strip("Money:")
    moneyc = re.search("(\*[^0,][0-9]{0,3})?(,[0-9]{3})?(,[0-9]{3})?", moneyc)
    moneyleft = re.sub("(\*[^0,][0-9]{0,3})?(,[0-9]{3})?(,[0-9]{3})? coins", "*"+str(int(moneyc.replace("*", "").replace(",", "")) - price)+" coins")
    money.write("Money\n"+moneyleft)
```

Returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/***/money.py", line 8, in <module>
    moneyleft = re.sub("(\*[^0,][0-9]{0,3})?(,[0-9]{3})?(,[0-9]{3})? coins", "*"+str(int(moneyc.replace("*", "").replace(",", "")) - price)+" coins")
AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

And it's just because regex match isn't a string, however since I need to turn it into a string somehow, how would I go about it?

What I want the file to be afterwards is:

```
Money:
*0 coins
*2 dollars
```

Due to the fact that the price is `500 * amount`, and amount is 2. Why I keep `"coins"` in my `re.sub` is because there's also dollars.

Comment: I think you included some js code in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues there:

1. You open the file only for reading with the modifier `r`, you should use `r+`.
2. Use the [`locale.atoi`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.atoi) function to validate and convert comma-separated integers.

Take a look at this code:

```
import locale
import re

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

recoins = re.compile(r'\*(\S+) coins')    
amount = 2
price = 500 * amount

with open('money.txt', 'r+') as money:
    text = money.read()
    coins = recoins.search(text).group(1)
    newcoins = locale.atoi(coins) - price
    money.seek(0)
    money.truncate()
    money.write(recoins.sub('*{:,} coins'.format(newcoins), text))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Money1_to_Money2(i) :
    Amount = i * 5
    print (Amount) 

Money1_to_Money2 (10)
```

This is a simple currency to currency code.
Just add the amount of money you want converted into the lower parentheses, then add the conversion factor where the 5 is. If you want it more organised put your currency to currency names instead of `money1` and `money2`; `i` equals the amount of money you have in the lower parentheses which is multiplied by conversion factor.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned from `re.search` function is a match object not a string.

That's why you get the error:

```
AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

To get the matching string after using `re.search` try:

```
moneyc = moneyc.group()
```

Then `moneyc.replace` will work.